# Swipe to delete listview shows artifacts

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, artifacts, swipe-gesture

I am trying to implement Chet Haase's swipe to delete, but the example he has provided is leaving artifacts, and a ghost list view item, once the number of items is less than the number to fill the screen.

Also, if you remove the background container mentioned, then you can see more weird artifacts.

[image: This image shows the artifacts when you swipe, after removing the background container]

[image: This shows the last item being repeated after the second item was removed by swiping]

The source code for the example is taken from here: [Graphics Geek Dev Bytes](http://developer.android.com/shareables/devbytes/ListViewItemAnimations.zip)

Comment: Can't you use another library?

Comment: @ChintanRathod could you mention examples of some? We are already using pull to refresh, so a drop in replacement won't work for us.

Comment: You may need to reassign the adapter once the list is updated. It seems that the adapter may keep the previous ghost value that is displayed

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement [SwipeListView](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview). It has same feature what you want.

[image]

Comment: the issue with this is, that this does not bring the other views up(or down) this simply shows another view behind the swiped list. We've done that, the issue is in removing the swiped item with animations.

Comment: so isn't it possible to modify that code like removing views behind views and simply set background white colored?

Comment: thats why we came here, to see what modifications have been done, but it seems to be creating some problems, that we have no idea about

Comment: @ChintanRathod will u please help me in this question will be thankfull to u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903545/how-to-call-framelayout-slider-in-diffrent-activties-in-android?noredirect=1#comment31377277_20903545

Comment: @ChintanRathod please help me in my issue ..please